# compressing a char into two bits only

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out how to compress a char (which is normally 1 byte) to 2 bits only.

For example I have a char array which contains a sequence of DNA molecule that goes like this :`"ACGGTTTT"`

It can only contain `A`, `T`, `G`, `C`

Now I decoded the chars like this : `A=0,C=1,G=2,T=3`, so I have this char array :`"01223333"`.

My question is how do I compress each char into two bits only which means `0=00,1=01,2=10,3=11` , and get this result :`"11111111 10100100"` in binary ?
notice that the result is from right to left.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: i didn't try anything, i actually have no clue on how to approach this .

Comment: Create an structure/object/container for storing the abstraction like `struct DNA_s { char *data; size_t datalen; }` with consistent interface/abstraction/API like `DNA_init(...)` `DNA_add_sequence` or `DNA_push_back` and `DNA_print` or `DNA_get_as_string` or similar. You compress the result normally, creating all the layers of abstraction for that. For storing the numbers as half-bytes just use bitshifts `char A = 0, C = 1, A_with_C = A << 4 | C;` What do you have a problem with? You may want to read [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Packing DNA sequences into 2-bit or 4-bit encoded data streams is not difficult, but accessing individual values from the sequence becomes clunky and inefficient.

If your goal is to compress the sequence for storage or transmission, you should just use a classic compression algorithm such as *gzip* provided by the `zlib` or more advanced ones such as *LZMA*, *LZ4* or *ZStandard*.

Comment: Accessing those values in read only should only be marginally slower (you add an and and a shift, which are very fast, especially compared to memory), and you make everything 75% smaller (better cache usage) still keeping O(1) random access; I wouldn't call this optimization worthless...

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I agree for random access of individual bases, but scanning a DNA sequence packed this way for subsequence matches with would not be just *marginally slower*...

Comment: I'm not so sure, once you get out of L2/L3 memory access tends to dominate pretty much any simple calculation... Also, substring matching can be made smarter to operate on such compressed data without actually unpacking it (although it's not completely trivial). But yes, of course you are right that the best representation heavily depends on the required access pattern.